# Merging 2 rows of a Table based on columns value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table having 3 columns : com_number, benef_1erticket_seult, benef_imp_ts_supports. Below is the data in the table :

[image]

I would like to have this data in another table having same 3 columns (com_number, benef_1erticket_seult, benef_imp_ts_supports)  but with a unique com_number. The condition is :

1. If a particular com_number in table 1 is having 2 or multiple rows and all the values in the column  benef_1erticket_seult is 'NO'/'OUI' then in table 2 this com_number will have a single line with 'NO'/'OUI' value.
2. Similarly, If a particular com_number in table 1 is having 2 or multiple rows and all the values in the column  benef_imp_ts_supports is 'NO'/'OUI' then in table 2 this com_number will have a single line with 'NO'/'OUI' value.
3. If a particular com_number in table 1 is having 2 or multiple rows and the values in the column  benef_imp_ts_supports /benef_1erticket_seult are having both 'NO' and 'OUI'  then in table 2 this com_number will have a single line with the value : 'MULTIPLE' for that specific column (Which is the case for com_number : 996754796).

Expected Result :

com_number  benef_1erticket_seult   benef_imp_ts_supports

```
996754796       NO                        MULTIPLE
993386349       NO                        NO    
994754177       NO                        OUI
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation and some conditional logic:

```
select com_number,
       (case when min(benef_1erticket_seult) = max(benef_1erticket_seult)
             then min(benef_1erticket_seult)
             else 'Multiple'
        end) as benef_1erticket_seult,
       (case when min(benef_imp_ts_supports) = max(benef_imp_ts_supports)
             then min(benef_imp_ts_supports)
             else 'Multiple'
        end) as benef_imp_ts_supports,
from t
group by com_number;
```